# Jquery: how to limit max number of items?

Tags: jquery

I have a Jquery form set up where I can add and remove fields: http://jsfiddle.net/beehive/TLJGb/

I don't want to be able to add more than 10 fields on this form. How can I accomplish this?

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;
    $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
        $('<p id="yum">beets ' + i + ' <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });
    $('#remScnt').live('click', function() {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

​
html:

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p id="yum">
        beets
    </p>
</div>
```

​

Comment: You cannot use the same ID on the `p` elements that you add, ID's are meant to be unique. The same goes for the `a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following if statement to your code...

```
$('#addScnt').live('click', function() {

    if ($(".item", addScnt).length < 9) {
        $('<p class="item" id="yum">beets ' + i +' <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
    }
        return false;
});
```

First I added a class to the items so I can detect them. Then I can count if there are less than 9 (+ the one you already had makes 10)

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLJGb/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the code that adds a new field in #addScnt's click handler in an if statement that checks if i is less than or equal to 10.

Or, in other words:

```
$('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
    if (i <= 10) {
        $('<p id="yum">beets ' + i + ' <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
    }
    return false;
});
```